# Rails: how to get the current host, or build a URL with it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, host

I need to use the host to build a URL with a different port.

For example, if the host is example.com, I need to generate a URL like http://example.com:8080/

I need it to be portable, so when I'm in my local enviroment it shows http://localhost:8080/ instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I often use a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` to set an instance variable with the host name, something like this:

```
@hostname = request.host || "www.mydomain.com"
```

You can also use `request.port` to get the port number which the request came through (taken from the HTTP headers).

Comment: request.host worked fine even in the views, thanks

Answer (score 14):

Basically you need to generate url based on the current url and some other port number.
it can be done as -

```
request.url(:port => 20)
```

On rails console

```
app.root_url(:port => 20)
 => "http://www.example.com:20/"
```

To extract host from url use

```
request.host
```